# Save additional instance fields when you save the file, in upload_to method

Tags: django, django-models

In a Doc model I have a FileField document:

```
document = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_to)
filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
file_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

At this moment the instance is not saved.

I want to add/set in the method `file_upload_to` the `filename` and `file_type`, before the Doc instance/model is saved.

'file_upload_to" is a callable, inside I tried o set:

`instance.filename = 'something'`, but is not working, is not modifying the real instance

Now, I'm doing it in the form:

```
 obj.filename = self.cleaned_data[document].name.lower())
 obj.file_type = self.cleaned_data[document].content_type.lower()
```

But, for Django Admin, is harder to create a custom inline formset/form, so I try to avoid it.

--

Below was suggested to use `save`.

The 'filename' and 'file_type' doesn't exist in the form are added programmatically.

The issue that I see is to access the attributes of the `document` field which is a `FileField` in the model, instead of the form. filename and file_type are actually attributes of the `FileField`

Comment: Have you considered overriding the `save()` method?

Comment: save() for the the Model no, because I need access to FileField attributes, save() for form yes, but I have issue in Django Admin inline, because is different than normal model save()